# Объединение двух таблиц MySQL

Tags: mysql

Работаю в **MySQL**
Задача следующая:

Есть таблица 1, в которой есть товары с полем "артикул"
В таблице 2 также есть данное поле

Необходимо добавить таблицу 2 в таблицу 1, но так, чтобы строки с одинаковыми
артикулами не добавлялись.

То есть:

**Table 1**
id      Имя        Артикул

1. Яблоко      111555
2. Груша       111222
3. Лимон       111888

**Table 2**

id      Имя        Артикул

1. Яблоко      222222
2. Грушаз      111222
3. ЛимонЗ      777777

**Итог**

id     имя         Артикул

1. Яблоко       111555
2. Груша        111222
3. Лимон        111888
4. Яблоко       222222
5. ЛимонЗ       777777

Comment: Грушаз ?...........

Comment: @Хан Бытый А где твое решение? Что уже сделал?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (
  `name`,
  `art`
) SELECT
  t2.`name`,
  t2.`art`
FROM
  table2 t2
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.`art` = t2.`art`)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @ХанБытый Если мой ответ помог Вам, отметьте его как правильный

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в первую таблицу уникальный индекс по полю `артикул`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_articul 
ON table1 (articul)
```

после чего просто вставляйте данные

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (name, articul)
SELECT name, articul FROM table2
```

Дубликаты сами не запишутся.

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так

```
SELECT
    name, articul
FROM
    table_1
WHERE
    articul NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT articul FROM table_2
    );
UNION
SELECT
    name, articul
FROM
    table_2
WHERE
    email NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT articul FROM table_1
    );
```